# Get consecutive t date range for each id in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with data like :

```
col1  col2
1      2020-01-15
1      2020-01-16
1      2020-01-17
1      2020-01-18
1      2020-01-20
2      2020-01-09
2      2020-01-10
2      2020-01-15
```

and I want output something like this

```
col1    min         max
1      2020-01-15  2020-01-18
1      2020-01-20  2020-01-20
2      2020-01-09  2020-01-10
2      2020-01-15  2020-01-15
```

As you can see for each Id I need date range for each consecutive ate chunk and if there is only one date then minmax will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0450d/4)** in the SQL Server.

```
select
  col1,
  min(col2) as mn,
  max(col2) as mx
from
(
  select
    col1,
    col2,
    date_sub(col2, -row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2)) as rnk
  from myTable
) val
group by
  col1,
  rnk
order by
  col1
```

Output:

```
*-------------------------------*
| col1      mn          mx      |
*-------------------------------*
| 1    2020-01-15    2020-01-18 |
| 1    2020-01-20    2020-01-20 |
| 2    2020-01-09    2020-01-10 |
| 2    2020-01-15    2020-01-15 |
*-------------------------------*
```

Comment: I tried this but the rank it is generating is not changing for a user for one the rant is coming 1 2 3 4 5 instead if 1 2 3 4 1

Comment: @KumarHarsh. . . What "rank" are you talking about?  Your question mentions no such rank.  This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then you should ask a *new* question.